# Personality test logic in PHP

Tags: php

I would like to make a "personality" test in PHP. I thought of making it with something like the following logic:

```
If $answer_one == "a" --> $personality_a = $personality_a+1;
If $answer_one == "b" --> $personality_b = $personality_b+1;
If $answer_one == "c" --> $personality_c = $personality_c+1;
If $answer_one == "d" --> $personality_d = $personality_d+1;

See which $personality_* is the highest one and then send the response.
```

How can I make something like this but possibly more generic using `foreach($_POST as $k => $v)`?

Comment: $personality_a = rand(). Faster ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are making the form as well, and are not interested in obscuring the test from 'view source' hacks

in the html, something along the lines of

```
<input type="radio" name="answer[1]" value="a">
```

in the code

```
<?php

$answers = array_count_values($_POST['answer']);

arsort($answers, SORT_NUMERIC);
reset($answers);
$personalityType = key($answers);

// TODO: validate type is valid
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy on the static code there my friend. You might consider a multidimensional array here

First create an answer array
    $answerArray = array('a','b','c','d')

Second, populate the user's responses in an array (called $userAnswers)

Then, compare the arrays using something like

```
$numCorrect = 0;
for($a; $a < count($answerArray); $a++){
    if($answerArray[$a] == $userAnswers[$a]){
        $numCorrect++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Whoa, Thanks Sammaye! I don't know what was wrong with that formatting.

Comment: There took out the weird HTML as well, you can use the `{}` button at the top, click it twice if the code doesnt format in the preview first time :)